# Extract Whole Number Value from XML Tag

Tags: xml, parsing, xmlstarlet

I'm trying to extract the temperature value (70°F) from a section of xml using `xmlstartlet`: `<variable var='T' description='Temp' unit='F' value='70'/>`

**XML Text (output.xml)**

```
<station id="KBOS" name="Boston, Logan International Airport" elev="20" lat="42.36056" lon="-71.01056" provider="NWS/FAA">
<ob time="25 Jul 7:05 am" utime="1564052700">
<variable var='T' description='Temp' unit='F' value='70'/>
```

**Attempted Code**

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m '/var='T'/description='Temp'/value=' -v . -n output.xml
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The literal answer to your question "what am I missing" seems to be "knowledge of XPath". Your query is a completely wild guess; you really need to do more reading before you start coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say for sure since your XML isn't a well-formed example, but try this:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "//variable[@var='T'][@description='Temp']/@value" -v . input.xml
```